# Angular 5 Error ng build --deploy-url

Tags: node.js, build, angular5

I was working with angular 4 with MVC. Recently we upgraded to Angular 5.
I got error in index.cshtml in the path $/Views/Home in MVC project at the following line:

```
fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/dist"));
```

> The command "ng build --deploy-url http://localhost:60859/dist/"
>   exited with code 3.

And I wasn't able to run the project, till I found my node.js version is 8.9.1 and the general version in the project is 6.11.5
I uninstalled mine, and re-install 6.11.5 version, then it worked.

But I still can see the error in **Error List**, and I have to build the project many times to have succeeded building.
Any idea about the problem?